# Understanding regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

i am trying to compare one buffer value using regular expression.

```
regexp {.*([0-9]+).*} $buffer match callID: $CallId
```

can you please explain what will be compared exactly in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your regexp, the `$CallId` is not correct. I assume that was a typo. Your regexp can be something like as follows,

```
 regexp {.*([0-9]+).*} $buffer match callID
```

It will check for the the pattern from the variable `buffer`. Basic syntax of `regexp` as follows,

> regexp ?switches? exp string ?matchVar? ?subMatchVar subMatchVar ...?

The variable `match` will hold the whole pattern, whereas the variable `callID` will have the 1st sub-match given by you. This is nothing but the numerical values matched in that text.

Sub-match is nothing but the expression given within parenthesis and each sub-match output will be saved in the subsequent variables given in the `regexp` command.

This expression can be visualized as below

[image: http://www.regexper.com/#.*(%5B0-9%5D%2B).*]

`.*` will match anything and it is greedy, which means it will try to match as much as possible. (it is not advisable unless absolute necessary).

`0-9` will match any numeric within 0 to 9 and usage of `+` will make sure to match one or more occurrence of numeric values within 0 to 9. (You can also use `\d` which is the equivalent of 0-9 range)

**Update :**

What is the content of the variable `buffer` ? The current regexp will match the last occurrence of numerical values. For example, lets say the content of buffer can be something like

```
set buffer "sometextherewithnumbers89sometext11211somemoretexthere891textstopshere"
```

If you apply the given regexp, then the output can be as follows,

```
 puts [  regexp {.*([0-9]+).*} $buffer match callID ]; # Prints '1' since it matched

 puts $match; # Prints whole buffer content

 puts $callID; # Prints the number '9', since it is the last digit in the buffer
```

**Output :**

```
1
sometextherewithnumbers89sometext11211somemoretexthere789textstopshere
9
```

As per the regular expression, we can separate it in the following way

```
.* --- part 1
([0-9]+)  --- part 2
.* --- part 3
```

As I pointed out earlier, `.*` is a greedy one which will try to match as much as possible. So, the `.*` at the beginning is matching up to `sometextherewithnumbers89sometext11211somemoretexthere78`. Then `([0-9]+)` will match the last digit `9`. At last, the `.*` will match the remaining text `textstopshere`.

Have a look at [here](http://regex101.com/r/uT6sE3/1) to visualize the matching pattern for the given example.

Comment: i have one more doubt as callID should be present in the buffer?.  and i need to retrive the callId from the buffer, how to do it?, in the output it will come as callId: 89 something like this i need this numerical value.

Comment: yes CallID value i.e. some numerical value should be present in the  variable `buffer`

Comment: @GauravKumar More detail about your buffer would be helpful. Do note that the current regex will take the *last single* digit from the buffer.

Comment: Actually i am trying to fetch callid from the output, the output is actually callid: 85 , something like this, how can we do it?

Comment: @GauravKumar Just use a regexp like this `regexp -nocase -- {callid: ([0-9]+)} $output -> CallID` and you will get a variable named `CallID` with the value `85`.